# Using jQuery-ui to autocomplete a text box with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to autocomplete a text box in my search.php code using autocomplete.php

I know that my php code works perfectly and echo's back exactly what is needed for the autocomplete function in jQuery.

Here is the html for the text box.

```
<input type="text" name='search' id="search" class="input-block-level" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search...">
```

Here is my script for the autocomplete function

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#search').autocomplete({source:'autocomplete.php', minLength:2});
  });
</script>
```

Here is the php file

```
<?php


 if ( !isset($_GET['term']) )
exit;


$conn = odbc_connect('Abilis', 'infosysreader', 'Wilsons12'); 

$query = "SELECT TOP 10 [Del_ad1] FROM [Abilis].[dbo].[Customers] WHERE Del_ad1 LIKE    '%".$_GET['term']."%'";

$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $query);



$data = array();

for($i = 0; $i<odbc_num_rows($rs);$i++){
$row = odbc_fetch_array($rs, $i);

$data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['Del_ad1'],
            'value' => $row['Del_ad1']
);
}

// jQuery wants JSON data
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

Edit:

I found my error at the end of my html file. It was just a mistake on my part, the method I use above works fine.

Comment: and whats the problem ?

Comment: stupid question....but shouldnt autocomplete be "on"?  maybe I dont understand

Comment: the autocomplete there is the browsers autocomplete to use with previous entries. It doesn't have anything to do with the jQuery autocomplete. It doesn't work when it is on or off.

Comment: if there is browsers autocomplete that means that your PHP script is never executed. Have you tried my way with ajax call ? Is your URL correct? check your source URL

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the URL and I have tried the ajax call, with no luck

Comment: see updated answer remove extra parameters from input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is but since your PHP correctly returns json encoded string then problem is with autocomplete call. Try this and let me know if it makes any difference:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
   minLength:2,
   source: function(request, response) {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'autocomplete.php', 
         dataType: 'json',
         data: { term : request.term },
         success: function(result) {
              response(result);
         }
       });
   }
});
```

Also try changing `autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="on"`

Remove the following from input element:

```
class="input-block-level" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search..."
```

and try with `<input type="text" name='search' id="search" />`

Comment: I tried that script with no luck, also tried to turn the autocomplete on and off. With no luck unfortunately.

Comment: No error messages at all. Nothing in the logs either. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: then try replacing `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` with `$(function() {` this and is this script located in the same file as html input element? are you including js file if its outside of input element? try alert('a') before autocomplete do you get alert message ?

Comment: It hits the alert when using my old code, but not with your ajax code.

Comment: because it was missing comma after minLength, try now